# YouTube Search no longer searches by URL. Why?

Tags: youtube-api

Until recently, you could paste a YouTube URL into a google/youtube search bar (or via the search API) and it would return that video in the search results. No longer.

What happened? Why did this functionality change? Believe it or not, tens of thousands of our users found this very useful and started complaining (loudly) when it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think the error is from you. This functionality works as well we expect.

You can try with this live example with the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-gQLqv9f4o with the [Google API's Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&q=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fwatch%253Fv%253Dl-gQLqv9f4o&_h=21&)

You just need to add the url of the video to the parameter `q` to the `youtube.search.list`

Comment: No, this was reported to me by hundreds of users. I tested it myself and confirmed it wasn't working anymore. Now, all of a sudden, it works again. Mission accomplished, I guess.